# Gender of the customer who made the order in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento2, magento-1.8

I want the SQL or the table relationships to find out the gender of the customer who made a particular order in magento.

Comment: what about 
`SELECT customer_prefix FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id = "100000XXXX";`

Comment: `customer_prefix` column is null. Is there any other way I can get the customer gender from?

Answer (score 0):

On my database it is:

```
SELECT t0.entity_id, t1.value
FROM customer_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.entity_id, t2.value
  FROM customer_entity_int AS t2
  WHERE (t2.attribute_id = 18)
  ) AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.entity_id)
```

Your `attribute_id = 18` might be different.

You need to find it on:

```
SELECT t1.attribute_id, t1.attribute_code, t1.backend_type
FROM eav_entity_type AS t0
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_type_id = t1.entity_type_id)
WHERE (t0.entity_model = @p0)
-- p0 = [customer/customer]
```